# How to print an excel document from command line with PRINT command in MSDOS

Tags: printing

Im trying to print an excel document through a default printer configured from command prompt using PRINT command as shown below:

C:>print c:\printdocs\test1.xls

by typing above and pressing enter a line saying 'C:\test1.xls is currently being printed'
is getting displayed but the excel document is not sent for default printer for printing. Please help me with this, where iam going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`print.exe` is designed to print a text file, and nothing else. In fact, if you type `print /?` from a command prompt, it tells you that in the first line of the text:

```
C:\>print /?
Prints a text file.

PRINT [/D:device] [[drive:][path]filename[...]]

   /D:device   Specifies a print device.
```

So the answer to your question is that you can't print an Excel file via `print` from the command line, because an `.XLS` file isn't a text file.

Comment: is there any other command or way to print the excel file, please help me with this.

Comment: i need to print multiple excel files silently in the background.cud any one please suggest me any command  or function or whatever way possible to do this in c++ ?

Comment: Can any one help me this ?